# Verb omission in English. "Enemy down" without any linking verb

Tags: verbs, phrases

Why are there no linking verbs in the following examples?

1. Enemy down
2. Feet dry
3. Feet wet
4. Mission completed

**Shouldn't it be "the enemy is downed" or "the enemy has been downed"?**

"the enemy has been downed" vs "enemy down"?

I know about headline style in newspapers but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This terse style of communication is common in radio communication, especially in military, aviation, shipping, etc situations. I recall the book title _Enemy Cost Ahead_ by Guy Gibson, a celebrated British World War 2 air force. It can be used in any situation where brevity is required, not just headlines.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey the same for all the 4 examples? And the difference where I mentioned "vs" is still not clear.

Comment: If a military fighter pilot said 'the enemy has been downed' then his commander would say 'that's three words too many'.

Comment: Where did you find 'feet dry' and 'feet wet'?

Comment: I should have typed 'Guy Gibson, a celebrated British World War 2 air force **officer**'

Comment: And one more: "game over"

Comment: And , @MichaelHarvey, *Enemy Co**a**st Ahead*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - more haste, less speed! There has been a controversy about Guy Gibson's dog, and its memorial stone.

Comment: Stuff without context like this cannot really be properly answered. Like: feet wet and feet dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When speaking in situations that require you to be terse, it is common not to use full sentences.

> Stop!

> Over there!

> Wolf!

> Ouch!

> Enemy down!

I suspect that most other languages allow this kind of utterance.

Many of these can be understood to be reduced from "X is Y" type sentences.  For example "Wolf!" would be "There is a wolf!"

The last one would be a communication by a fighter pilot in a dog-fight. And would be understood as "The enemy is down" (another "X is Y" sentence).

You would *not* normally say "feet wet", though the same principle can apply.

Comment: Thank you James. What can you say about "game over" and "7 left"? What is the full form of "7 left"?

Comment: The game is over,  There are seven left, or "Seven (things) are left.

Comment: "the enemy has been downed" vs "enemy down"? @James

Comment: There is a verb "to down", but wielding occam's razor, the simplest understanding is "The enemy is down" or "There is an enemy down".  "Down" is an adjective. No need to suppose it is a verb (in some kind of subjunctive?)

Comment: ok. then "enemy spotted" vs "enemy has been spotted" ?

Comment: Yes, but using a participle instead of an adjective is common enough.  You would need a perfect aspect "An enemy has been spotted (by me)"  It is still an "is" type sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I see that linking verbs are omitted when we want to quickly convey information (radio communication, newspapers).
1. Are there any other cases when linking verbs are omitted (firefighters without radio?)?
2. Do military omit linking verbs during communication without radio when they're at war?
3. Do videogames omit linking verbs for the same reason as newspapers?

Comment: Too many questions to answer.  Most of these questions are not about learning English but are about [english.se]